# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined "Javascript"

Tags: javascript

I am working on eight tile puzzle problem.

I am getting an

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error
>   while running this code:

```
for ( i = 0; i <= 2; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j <= 2; j++ ) {
        startStateArr[i][j] = document.getElementById("start" + i + j).value;
    }
}
```

Div ID's are as follows: start00, start01, start02, start10, start11, start12, start20, start21, start22.

Comment: Is `startStateArr` defined?

Comment: @AjJohnson Yes, it's.

Comment: @Olian04 But, Javascript is fully capable of handling this. It automatically converts other numbers into string even if only one value is in string.

Comment: @wished it actually works because the string is before the numbers, if it was at the end they would get added.

Comment: @wished Yes you are correct, however it's not because `It automatically converts other numbers into string even if only one value is in string`. Its because js is left coercive (and not right coercive as my failing memory told me). Aka: `'h'+1+2 = 'h12'` but `1+2+'h' = '3h'`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Exactly, I wonder why it's not working properly in my code.

Comment: @Olian04 Absolutely ^.^

Comment: _" I wonder why it's not working properly in my code."_ The problem is not the `getElementById()` call

Comment: @Andreas Hmm, so it's something else which is causing the issue.

Comment: the answer by @Suren-srapyan solves your issue. The array needs to be initialized and each element need to have another array (like a 2d array)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yep, thanks a lot it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your second level arrays - `startStateArr[i] = []`. Do the same for the main array if not

```
var startStateArr = []; // If not done

for ( i = 0; i <= 2; i++ ) {
    startStateArr[i] = []; // Look at this line
    for ( j = 0; j <= 2; j++ ) {
        startStateArr[i][j] = document.getElementById("start" + i + j).value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped ^.^